# Can't update records in my Rails database migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-migrations

For example I have the following migration

```
class AddStatusField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :tasks, :status, :string
    Task.update_all "status='complete'", "completed = 't'"
    remove_column :tasks, :completed
  end
end
```

When I run this (using `rake db:migrate`) I get the following message

```
==  AddStatusField: migrating =================================================
-- add_column(:tasks, :status, :string)
   -> 0.0010s
-- update_all("status='complete'", "completed = 't'")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `update_all' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0xd3d34a8>
```

If I immediately run the migration it again the `update_all` calls appear to work.

I'm using Rails 2.3.5 and sqlite3.

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it might be a naming conflict with `Task`. Does it fail with any other class in your application or just `Task`?

You might be able to call it using `::Task` to indicate that you want the `Task` class in the root namespace. Rake, for example, defines its own `Task` class and it's possible that something in the migration process is doing the same.

Comment: Ah-ha, I think you might be right Shadwell.  I tried prefixing with `::` but that made no difference.  I just tested with a different model and that works fine.  So... how can I avoid having to rename my `Task` model?

Comment: Sure enough, `Task` appears in http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords.  Dammnit!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
Task.reset_column_information
```

right before your update_all

Comment: That gives me: `undefined method 'reset_column_information' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0
xd367598>`

Comment: Voldy, no, the second parameter `"completed = 't'"` is my condition (i.e. where-clause).  Besides, the error message I'm getting is that `update_all` doesn't exist.